# How to set up listener for a piece of code in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, I need a listener for a short piece of code which returns something, so it detects if the value returned of that code has changed. And when I mean short piece of code, I mean like calling a function that returns something. I know they have something similar this for variables:

```
var anyVariableNameYouWant by Delegates.observable("the value to set it to") { property, oldValue, newValue ->
    Log.i(TAG, "The new value is $newValue")
}
```

But even if I set "the value to set it to" to the line of code, and the value returned changes, it doesn't show the log message.
So that didn't work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Using your example, if I add the line `anyVariableNameYouWant = "a new string"` after the variable declaration I get the output `"The new value is a new string"`

Comment: But for example, let's say that it was `anyVariableNameYouWant by Delegates.observable(value)` and value was `var value = "asdf"` and you added the line `value = "a new value here!"` This wouldn't output something. If you have any further questions please ask.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the `Delegate` feature of Kotlin. I've not used them myself so can't provide any guidance apart from a link to the docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to create a callback/listener. You should be able to reuse the example below.

```
class Event(
   val onExecuted: () -> Unit
)
```

Then you can call it like this

```
fun doWork() {
    val event = Event(
        onExecuted = {
           // This gets called later. 
        }
    )
    processEvent(event)
}
```

This is how you make the callback.

```
fun processEvent(event: Event) {
    event.onExecuted()
}
```

Comment: Where do I put my line of code as said in my question?